# android.permission.INTERNET not working

Tags: android

So according to the android api all you have to do is add the permission.INTERNET in the manifest to allow an app to connect to the internet. I have done this and it still doesn't work. I post the manifest here, if anyone can give any insight into why this could be I would be very greatful.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest package="com.example.psat"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0"        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity

                android:name="com.example.psat.ProsperitasSAT"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Here is the part that handles the logic of the webpage fetching:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prosperitas_sat);
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.dataWindow)).getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.dataWindow)).loadUrl("www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: looks ok to me,  whats the error/stacktrace and code that is going unexpectedly.

Comment: Nothing, I run the application and it just can't access the internet. =/

Comment: Do you have any code that fetches stuff (http requests) from the internet.  Maybe in ProsperitasSAT.java? [Example of simple HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: a simple webview.loadURL("www.google.com"), nothing too fancy atm since i'm only testing the connectivity.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add that part of the that handles the logic for the webview? From there may be able to see what is going on/missing.

Comment: check if you have mobile data transfer enabled/wi-fi enabled

Comment: I do, I use my phone for all sorts of things internet related =) I also edited my question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the "http://" of the url:

```
((WebView) findViewById(R.id.dataWindow)).loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding both.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`